# An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is similar to its transpose $A^{\top}$: elementary proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-theory, similarity

A famous result in linear algebra is the following.

> An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is similar to its transpose $A^T$.

I know one proof using the Smith Normal Form (SNF). However, I want to find an elementary proof avoiding any concepts related to the SNF. My question is: is there an elementary way to prove this?

The requirements are:

- Do NOT use the structure theorem over PID.
- Do NOT use the Smith Normal form (nor Jordan canonical form).
- Do NOT use the concept of invariant factors.
- Provide an explicit invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=PA^T P^{-1}$.

Comment: This is a lot like looking for a proof which does not need the letter a in order to be written down :-) What exactly do you  mean by elementary? The Jordan canonical form is basic linear algebra, really.

Comment: @Mariano: Yeah, it might not be possible to avoid those to prove it. The matrix P coming from Jordan canonical form proof is already complicated enough. Maybe requiring to provide explicit P is not possible without those. The generalized eigenvectors are involved and an inversion that transforms Jordan block to its transpose. 

Comment: There is a proof using rational canonical form, which basically just needs the fact that $A$ and $A^{t}$ have the same minimum polynomial, but I don't think that will be considered explicit .enough

Comment: It's easy to prove using normal forms, but you can reframe it as the statement that if $A:V\to V$ is linear then there is a nondegenerate bilinear form on $V$ such that $\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v, Aw\rangle$ identically. Is there any chance of a proof of this that is quite different from the normal-form proofs? 

Comment: In the two by two case $P$ can always be chosen to be symmetric. Is this true in general?


Comment: @Geoff: the fact that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same minimal polynomial is obvious: if $p(A)=0$, then $p(A^T)=p(A)^T=0$. 

Comment: @Tom: This link http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pjm/1103039127

Comment: This is slightly related to my question <a href="http:mathoverflow.net/questions/42072</a>

Comment: @MarkSapir : Yes, of course the fact that $A$ and $A^{T}$ have the same minimum polynomial is obvious: it was the use of rational canonical form ( which is really more general that Jordan Normal Form) that seemed to be outside the spirit of the question.

Comment: Is the proof given here http://msp.org/pjm/1959/9-3/pjm-v9-n3-p25-p.pdf sufficiently "elementary"? Incidentally, note the remark on p.895 (pdf 4/7) comes from M. Newman; there was an earlier MO question answered using Smith's work (which you wish to avoid here...) that turned out to have a more elementary solution from M. Newman (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151166/a-function-composed-with-itself-produces-the-identity/). If the linked proof here does not suffice, perhaps Newman is the fellow to look to...

Comment: @BenjaminDickman The first link shows that the solution space of $XA=A^T X$, $X=X^T$ has at least dimension $n$. However, the paper does not discuss how to obtain a "nonsingular" matrix in the solution space. That was actually a motivation of my question.

Comment: See http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103039127. Maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62497/matrix-is-conjugate-to-its-own-transpose#comment146005_62497 is related.

Comment: @i707107 Can you read some french papers ?

Comment: @Julien I know very little french, but there is google translate.

Comment: @i707107 So, I hope you can work with this : http://www.sujets-de-concours.net/sujets/centrale/2003/tsi/math2.pdf , look at Partie V, it's an elementary approach. The solution here : http://pomux.free.fr/corriges-2003/index.html

Comment: @user46896 The method is interesting, but not very far from Jordan canonical form (see questions V.B.1. and V.B.2.). One dreams about an algorithm providing $P$ from scratch ...

Comment: After many years this question was first asked, I cannot find anything meeting all of my requirement. Actually, finding Smith Normal Form can be done through elementary row/column operations. So, it is already elementary enough, and I do not have any reason left for avoiding such a simple and powerful tool. Also, SNF provides not only the existence of $P$, but also an explicit way to write down a such $P$.